# PHPのif文の条件式で、$valueにどんな値が入っていれば trueが表示される結果となりますか？

Tags: php

以下はphpコードの抜粋ですが、以下のコードで`"true"` と表示される結果にするためには、 
`$value` にはどのような値を入れればよろしいでしょうか？　また、そもそもそのような`$value`の値が存在するのでしょうか？
`"true"` と表示される条件が見つかりません。

```
<?php 
$value =？; 
if (!isset($value)) return; 
if (is_null($value)) return; 
if (is_scalar($value) && $value === "") return; 
if (is_array($value) && count($value) == 0) return; 

if ($value != true && $value != false){ 
        echo "true"; 
}else{ 
        echo "false"; 
}
```

$valueに、`true`、`false`、`1`、`0`、`1`、`"1"`、`"0"`、`'1'`、`'0'`、`array("a","b")`とかを入れてもダメでした。

Answer (score 2):

変数名が変わってしまっているのでそこがダメですが、
以下の様な いかさまをすれば trueは出力させることができるという事で。

マジックメソッドのうち
__issetをオーバーロードして常に1を返しながら、
__getをオーバーロードしてプロパティにアクセスするとtrueとfalseになるような値が交互に取れるようにしています。
（評価するたびに値が変わるので !=true 且つ !=false が成り立ってしまいます。完全に副作用です。）

```
<?php

class TestClass{
   public function __isset($name){
       return 1;
   }

   private $v="1";
   public function __get($name){
        if($this->v=="1"){
               $this->v="0";
        }else{
               $this->v="1";
        }
        return $this->v;
   }
}

$x = new TestClass();
// $value ではなく $x->value にしているので、質問とは異なる。

if (!isset($x->value)) return;         
   // valueは宣言されてませんが issetが常に1を返すので通過
if (is_null($x->value)) return;
if (is_scalar($x->value) && $x->value === "") return;
if (is_array($x->value) && count($x->value) == 0) return;

// この段階で次に$x->valueを取り出すと"0"が取れ、文字列"0"はfalseとされるので != trueです。
// 且つ、 その次のアクセスでは $x->value は "1"が取れるので、文字列"1"は !=falseです。

if ($x->value != true && $x->value != false){
        echo "true";
}else{
        echo "false";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

マジックメソッドがアリならSPLもアリだよね。配列のインデックス指定でもごまかせる。

```
<?php 
class SplDamn extends ArrayObject {
    private $pos = 0;
    public function offsetGet($i) {
        return parent::offsetGet(++$this->pos - 1);
    }
}

$value = new SplDamn(array(
    "isset",
    "!is_null",
    "is_scalar",
    "!is_array",
    false,
    true
));

if (!isset($value[0])) return; 
if (is_null($value[0])) return; 
if (is_scalar($value[0]) && $value[0] === "") return; 
if (is_array($value[0]) && count($value[0]) == 0) return; 

if ($value[0] != true && $value[0] != false){ 
    echo "true"; 
} else {
    echo "false"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

gmp の演算子のオーバーロードが実装されている PHP のバージョン限定です（5.6）。

```
<?php
$value = gmp_init(2);

if (!isset($value)) return;
if (is_null($value)) return;
if (is_scalar($value) && $value === "") return;
if (is_array($value) && count($value) == 0) return;

if ($value != true && $value != false){
        echo "true";
}else{
        echo "false";
}
```

実行すると、

```
$ php a.php
true
```

個々の理由は次の通りです。

```
<?php
$value = gmp_init(2);

var_dump(!isset($value));       // false オブジェクトです
var_dump(is_null($value));      // false null ではない
var_dump(is_scalar($value));    // false スカラーではない
var_dump($value === "");        // false 空文字ではない
var_dump(is_array($value));     // false 配列ではない
var_dump(count($value) == 0);   // false なぜか count すると 1 です → count(2) になっている？
var_dump($value != true);       // true  2 != 1 になっている？
var_dump($value != false);      // true  2 != 0 になっている？
```